# Create VectorDrawable from String (path)?

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

Is there a way to get SVG path string from the API and create `VectorDrawable` dynamically?

I have been trying to do this for hours without success. Even more, all (!) examples on the Internet explain creating `VectorDrawable` from XML resources.

In my case, XML resource file is pointless as I am trying to fetch SVG path from the Internet API.

Comment: Bear in mind that [getting arbitrary SVG to work with `VectorDrawable` is difficult](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/vectors-for-all-almost), even when you are doing it at compile time. That being said, the JavaDocs do not appear to exclude the possibility of [using `inflate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html#inflate%28android.content.res.Resources,%20org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser,%20android.util.AttributeSet,%20android.content.res.Resources.Theme%29) on an `XmlPullParser` that comes from a file, instead of from resources.

Answer (score 21):

Inflating a drawable from a XML file instead of from resources is actually impossible, because the drawable will try to cast the `XmlPullParser` to `XmlResourceParser` which is only implemented by private class `XmlBlock.Parser`. Even that parser is only used for parsing binary XML files. I tried every possible way of doing this without reflection, it's impossible.

So I found [documentation on binary XML](https://justanapplication.wordpress.com/category/android/android-binary-xml/) files and learned how they were made, helped with some compiled binary XML vector drawable files I had. The documentation dates back to 2011 and is still valid, I guess it will most likely remain this way, so future compatibility isn't an issue.

A previous version was tested for more than a thousand paths, without problem. The new version posted here should work just as well. (Previous versions are available in the [answer history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49920860/revisions)) Compared with loading a drawable directly from resources, I found that there's an average of 14 microseconds or so of extra loading, not noticeable.

Here's the code:

```
public class VectorDrawableCreator {

    private static final byte[][] BIN_XML_STRINGS = {
            "width".getBytes(),
            "height".getBytes(),
            "viewportWidth".getBytes(),
            "viewportHeight".getBytes(),
            "fillColor".getBytes(),
            "pathData".getBytes(),
            "path".getBytes(),
            "vector".getBytes(),
            "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android".getBytes()
    };

    private static final int[] BIN_XML_ATTRS = {
            android.R.attr.height, 
            android.R.attr.width, 
            android.R.attr.viewportWidth,
            android.R.attr.viewportHeight, 
            android.R.attr.fillColor, 
            android.R.attr.pathData
    };

    private static final short CHUNK_TYPE_XML = 0x0003;
    private static final short CHUNK_TYPE_STR_POOL = 0x0001;
    private static final short CHUNK_TYPE_START_TAG = 0x0102;
    private static final short CHUNK_TYPE_END_TAG = 0x0103;
    private static final short CHUNK_TYPE_RES_MAP = 0x0180;

    private static final short VALUE_TYPE_DIMENSION = 0x0500;
    private static final short VALUE_TYPE_STRING = 0x0300;
    private static final short VALUE_TYPE_COLOR = 0x1D00;
    private static final short VALUE_TYPE_FLOAT = 0x0400;


    /**
     * Create a vector drawable from a list of paths and colors
     * @param width drawable width
     * @param height drawable height
     * @param viewportWidth vector image width
     * @param viewportHeight vector image height
     * @param paths list of path data and colors
     * @return the vector drawable or null it couldn't be created.
     */
    public static Drawable getVectorDrawable(@NonNull Context context,
                                             int width, int height,
                                             float viewportWidth, float viewportHeight,
                                             List<PathData> paths) {
        byte[] binXml = createBinaryDrawableXml(width, height, viewportWidth, viewportHeight, paths);

        try {
            // Get the binary XML parser (XmlBlock.Parser) and use it to create the drawable
            // This is the equivalent of what AssetManager#getXml() does
            @SuppressLint("PrivateApi")
            Class<?> xmlBlock = Class.forName("android.content.res.XmlBlock");
            Constructor xmlBlockConstr = xmlBlock.getConstructor(byte[].class);
            Method xmlParserNew = xmlBlock.getDeclaredMethod("newParser");
            xmlBlockConstr.setAccessible(true);
            xmlParserNew.setAccessible(true);
            XmlPullParser parser = (XmlPullParser) xmlParserNew.invoke(
                    xmlBlockConstr.newInstance((Object) binXml));

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
                return Drawable.createFromXml(context.getResources(), parser);
            } else {
                // Before API 24, vector drawables aren't rendered correctly without compat lib
                final AttributeSet attrs = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);
                int type = parser.next();
                while (type != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    type = parser.next();
                }
                return VectorDrawableCompat.createFromXmlInner(context.getResources(), parser, attrs, null);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(VectorDrawableCreator.class.getSimpleName(), "Vector creation failed", e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static byte[] createBinaryDrawableXml(int width, int height,
                                                  float viewportWidth, float viewportHeight,
                                                  List<PathData> paths) {
        List<byte[]> stringPool = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(BIN_XML_STRINGS));
        for (PathData path : paths) {
            stringPool.add(path.data);
        }

        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(8192);  // Capacity might have to be greater.
        bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

        int posBefore;

        // ==== XML chunk ====
        // https://justanapplication.wordpress.com/2011/09/22/android-internals-binary-xml-part-two-the-xml-chunk/
        bb.putShort(CHUNK_TYPE_XML);  // Type
        bb.putShort((short) 8);  // Header size
        int xmlSizePos = bb.position();
        bb.position(bb.position() + 4);

        // ==== String pool chunk ====
        // https://justanapplication.wordpress.com/2011/09/15/android-internals-resources-part-four-the-stringpool-chunk/
        int spStartPos = bb.position();
        bb.putShort(CHUNK_TYPE_STR_POOL);  // Type
        bb.putShort((short) 28);  // Header size
        int spSizePos = bb.position();
        bb.position(bb.position() + 4);
        bb.putInt(stringPool.size());  // String count
        bb.putInt(0);  // Style count
        bb.putInt(1 << 8);  // Flags set: encoding is UTF-8
        int spStringsStartPos = bb.position();
        bb.position(bb.position() + 4);
        bb.putInt(0);  // Styles start

        // String offsets
        int offset = 0;
        for (byte[] str : stringPool) {
            bb.putInt(offset);
            offset += str.length + (str.length > 127 ? 5 : 3);
        }

        posBefore = bb.position();
        bb.putInt(spStringsStartPos, bb.position() - spStartPos);
        bb.position(posBefore);

        // String pool
        for (byte[] str : stringPool) {
            if (str.length > 127) {
                byte high = (byte) ((str.length & 0xFF00 | 0x8000) >>> 8);
                byte low = (byte) (str.length & 0xFF);
                bb.put(high);
                bb.put(low);
                bb.put(high);
                bb.put(low);
            } else {
                byte len = (byte) str.length;
                bb.put(len);
                bb.put(len);
            }
            bb.put(str);
            bb.put((byte) 0);
        }

        if (bb.position() % 4 != 0) {
            // Padding to align on 32-bit
            bb.put(new byte[4 - (bb.position() % 4)]);
        }

        // Write string pool chunk size
        posBefore = bb.position();
        bb.putInt(spSizePos, bb.position() - spStartPos);
        bb.position(posBefore);

        // ==== Resource map chunk ====
        // https://justanapplication.wordpress.com/2011/09/23/android-internals-binary-xml-part-four-the-xml-resource-map-chunk/
        bb.putShort(CHUNK_TYPE_RES_MAP);  // Type
        bb.putShort((short) 8);  // Header size
        bb.putInt(8 + BIN_XML_ATTRS.length * 4);  // Chunk size
        for (int attr : BIN_XML_ATTRS) {
            bb.putInt(attr);
        }

        // ==== Vector start tag ====
        int vstStartPos = bb.position();
        int vstSizePos = putStartTag(bb, 7, 4);

        // Attributes
        // android:width="24dp", value type: dimension (dp)
        putAttribute(bb, 0, -1, VALUE_TYPE_DIMENSION, (width << 8) + 1);

        // android:height="24dp", value type: dimension (dp)
        putAttribute(bb, 1, -1, VALUE_TYPE_DIMENSION, (height << 8) + 1);

        // android:viewportWidth="24", value type: float
        putAttribute(bb, 2, -1, VALUE_TYPE_FLOAT, Float.floatToRawIntBits(viewportWidth));

        // android:viewportHeight="24", value type: float
        putAttribute(bb, 3, -1, VALUE_TYPE_FLOAT, Float.floatToRawIntBits(viewportHeight));

        // Write vector start tag chunk size
        posBefore = bb.position();
        bb.putInt(vstSizePos, bb.position() - vstStartPos);
        bb.position(posBefore);

        for (int i = 0; i < paths.size(); i++) {
            // ==== Path start tag ====
            int pstStartPos = bb.position();
            int pstSizePos = putStartTag(bb, 6, 2);

            // android:fillColor="#aarrggbb", value type: #rgb.
            putAttribute(bb, 4, -1, VALUE_TYPE_COLOR, paths.get(i).color);

            // android:pathData="...", value type: string
            putAttribute(bb, 5, 9 + i, VALUE_TYPE_STRING, 9 + i);

            // Write path start tag chunk size
            posBefore = bb.position();
            bb.putInt(pstSizePos, bb.position() - pstStartPos);
            bb.position(posBefore);

            // ==== Path end tag ====
            putEndTag(bb, 6);
        }

        // ==== Vector end tag ====
        putEndTag(bb, 7);

        // Write XML chunk size
        posBefore = bb.position();
        bb.putInt(xmlSizePos, bb.position());
        bb.position(posBefore);

        // Return binary XML byte array
        byte[] binXml = new byte[bb.position()];
        bb.rewind();
        bb.get(binXml);

        return binXml;
    }

    private static int putStartTag(ByteBuffer bb, int name, int attributeCount) {
        // https://justanapplication.wordpress.com/2011/09/25/android-internals-binary-xml-part-six-the-xml-start-element-chunk/
        bb.putShort(CHUNK_TYPE_START_TAG);
        bb.putShort((short) 16);  // Header size
        int sizePos = bb.position();
        bb.putInt(0); // Size, to be set later
        bb.putInt(0);  // Line number: None
        bb.putInt(-1);  // Comment: None

        bb.putInt(-1);  // Namespace: None
        bb.putInt(name);
        bb.putShort((short) 0x14);  // Attributes start offset
        bb.putShort((short) 0x14);  // Attributes size
        bb.putShort((short) attributeCount);  // Attribute count
        bb.putShort((short) 0);  // ID attr: none
        bb.putShort((short) 0);  // Class attr: none
        bb.putShort((short) 0);  // Style attr: none

        return sizePos;
    }

    private static void putEndTag(ByteBuffer bb, int name) {
        // https://justanapplication.wordpress.com/2011/09/26/android-internals-binary-xml-part-seven-the-xml-end-element-chunk/
        bb.putShort(CHUNK_TYPE_END_TAG);
        bb.putShort((short) 16);  // Header size
        bb.putInt(24);  // Chunk size
        bb.putInt(0);  // Line number: none
        bb.putInt(-1);  // Comment: none
        bb.putInt(-1);  // Namespace: none
        bb.putInt(name);  // Name: vector
    }

    private static void putAttribute(ByteBuffer bb, int name,
                                     int rawValue, short valueType, int valueData) {
        // https://justanapplication.wordpress.com/2011/09/19/android-internals-resources-part-eight-resource-entries-and-values/#struct_Res_value
        bb.putInt(8);  // Namespace index in string pool (always the android namespace)
        bb.putInt(name);
        bb.putInt(rawValue);
        bb.putShort((short) 0x08);  // Value size
        bb.putShort(valueType);
        bb.putInt(valueData);
    }


    public static class PathData {

        public byte[] data;
        public int color;

        public PathData(byte[] data, int color) {
            this.data = data;
            this.color = color;
        }

        public PathData(String data, int color) {
            this(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), color);
        }

    }

}
```

A call to `getVectorDrawable` returns a `VectorDrawable` from a list of paths. The drawable can contain multiple paths with different colors. There are also parameters for the drawable and viewport size.

Here's an example:

```
List<PathData> pathList = Arrays.asList(new PathData("M128.09 5.02a110.08 110.08 0 0 0-110 110h220a109.89 109.89 0 0 0-110-110z", Color.parseColor("#7cb342")),
                    new PathData("M128.09 115.02h-110a110.08 110.08 0 0 0 110 110 110.08 110.08 0 0 0 110-110z", Color.parseColor("#8bc34a")),
                    new PathData("M207.4 115.2v-.18h-5.1l-61.43-61.43h-25.48v20.6h-6.5a11.57 11.57 0 0 0-11.53 11.53v26.09h.11c-.11.9.5 2 1.7 3.32.12.08.12.08.12.2l3.96 4-46.11 79.91c5.33 4.5 11.04 8.4 17 11.8a109.81 109.81 0 0 0 108.04 0 110.04 110.04 0 0 0 51.52-64.65c.38-1.28.68-2.57 1.1-3.78z", Color.parseColor("#30000000")),
                    new PathData("M216.28 230.24a6.27 6.27 0 0 0-.9-2.8l-31.99-55.57-10.58-18.48-19.85-34.21-15.08 15.12 18.6 32.28 10.2 17.73 30.92 53.37a5.6 5.6 0 0 0 1.97 2.12l15.42 10.5c.6.39 1.29.39 1.9.08.6-.37.9-.98.9-1.7z", Color.parseColor("#e1e1e1")),
                    new PathData("M186.98 115.02a58.9 58.9 0 0 1-30.5 51.6 58.4 58.4 0 0 1-56.7 0l18.6-32.28-15.13-15.12-62.48 108.22c-.5.9-.8 1.78-.9 2.8l-1.4 18.6c-.12.71.3 1.28.9 1.7.6.37 1.29.3 1.9-.12l15.41-10.4a7.87 7.87 0 0 0 1.97-2.07l30.92-53.53a78.74 78.74 0 0 0 77.23 0 76.65 76.65 0 0 0 16.6-12.4 79.3 79.3 0 0 0 24.07-56.89z", Color.parseColor("#f1f1f1")),
                    new PathData("M147.3 74.12h-6.43v-20.6h-25.48v20.6h-6.5a11.57 11.57 0 0 0-11.53 11.5v26.07h.11c-.11 1.02.5 2.12 1.82 3.4l23.05 23.14a8.3 8.3 0 0 0 5.75 2.38v-.07l.07.07c2.12 0 4.2-.75 5.71-2.38l23.1-23.1c1.32-1.32 1.81-2.53 1.81-3.4h.12V85.7a11.68 11.68 0 0 0-11.6-11.6zm-19.14 40.9h-.07a15.4 15.4 0 0 1 0-30.8v-.2l.07.2a15.46 15.46 0 0 1 15.31 15.38 15.46 15.46 0 0 1-15.3 15.42z", Color.parseColor("#646464")));
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please describe how to add color and size to the byte arrays?

Comment: @SinaRezaei Yes I had a more complete version built with a ByteBuffer, I'll edit my answer soon...

Comment: @SinaRezaei I just added the complete code. There's already a color parameter provided. The drawable size can be changed on lines 108 and 115 simply by changing the value in hex. The viewport size can be changed on lines 122 and 129 by changing the value to the float representation of the dimension. To achieve this, I suggest you use something like [this website](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=050052) or `Float.floatToIntBits(float)` if it's not fixed. If I get the time, I'll create a more complete version with size parameters entered automatically.

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas, I'm having an issue with implementing a vector with multiple path tags inside. I used your method and updated the code but it's not working. Can you have a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55540796/create-vector-drawable-from-string-with-multiple-path-tags-android ?

Comment: @SinaRezaei I've updated my answer it should work now.

Comment: Suppose I have a byte-array of the data for VectorDrawable, is it possible to get a VectorDrawable out of it?  Also, it doesn't seem that VectorDrawable consists only of PathData list: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html . Here, asked about it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59022749/878126

Comment: @Nicolas i tried to upgrade your class introducing strokeColor and strokeWidth properties to path tag. The XML generated seems to be correct ( i used the XmlPullParser class to log it) but stroke is not visible and I found the following error in the logcat: E/ComplexColorCompat: Failed to inflate ComplexColor.
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @Jon_Snow Did you add the `android:strokeColor` and `android:strokeWidth` attributes to the `BIN_XML_ATTRS` and `BIN_XML_STRINGS` arrays? They need to have the same indices I think, so you'll have to shift other attributes. Make sure all indices referring the both arrays are correct everywhere after shifting.

Comment: @Nicolas yes sure, i fixed the indices but I still have the same error. It seems that strokeColor and fillColor are handled in different ways. Here's the code if you want to take a look: https://github.com/andreanzi/Android-SVG-path-rendering/blob/master/VectorDrawableCreator.java. As you can see, I started coding to support also group tag

Comment: working as a charm, ty :)

Answer (score 0):

@Andre.Anzi To extend the class to support `strokeColor` and `strokeWidth`, you can try to arrange the attributes in an alphabetical order.